# How to play video from ePub by using iPhone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, epub

I have ePub file with me which contain video in it. I am able to unzip ePub file & added it into my xcode project also shown that file in to my application. But I am not able to play video from that ePub file. How can play that video?